# my javascript function is not called on button click

Tags: javascript, events

I have this code:

```
<script language="javascript">
var noun=["cat","mat","rat"];
var verb=["like","is","see","sees"];
var object=["me","a+noun","the+noun"];
var subject=["I","a+noun","the+noun"];
var sentence=(subject+verb+object);

function checkCorrectness(){
    var input=document.getElementbyId("userInput");
    if(input==sentence)
        {
        alert("congratulations your sentence is correct");
        }
    else if(input=="null"||"")
        {
        alert("your entered a blank text, please enter sentence");
        }
    else{
        alert("Sorry, Your sentence is incorrect, your sentence should be in the form of a subject, verb and object. please try again");
        }
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1><font size="3" color="black" face="comic sans ms">Welcome to Micro English</font></h1>
<h2><font size="2" color="blue" face="comic sans ms">Please Enter a sentence in micro English in the box below</font></h2>

<form onsubmit="checkCorrectness();">
<input type="text" name="input" id="userInput"/>
<input type="submit"value="go"/>
</form>
```

but when I click the "go" button nothing happens.what could be the problem? I have tried changing the type of input but it has never ran, I had a similar program that did run but I just cnt put my finger on the problem here. please help

Comment: You're comparing the element itself, not its value - should be `var input=document.getElementbyId("userInput").value;`

Comment: What does *value`enter code here`* supposed to mean?

Comment: What is this `value`enter code here`` ?

Comment: Also, `else if(input=="null"||"")` - you're checking for string comparison against the string `"null"`, which I'm assuming is not what you want. Plus the `||""` won't work - the language doesn't work that way. You probably want `if (!input)`, which will look for any "falsy" value.

Comment: Joe I did try that but the same thing happens, the page loads but when I enter text into the textbox and click on  the button nothing happens

Comment: @dodo and DontVoteMeDown - that's a SO editor typo - if you hit the code button on the editor while in text, that appears. Definitely not part of the question.

Comment: * document.getElementById("userInput");..use  B instead of b (your mistake)

Comment: @DaphumlestNthabieMoloi what do you think sentence=(subject+verb+object) is doing?

Comment: @Christophe the user is supposed to enter sentences using the verb,noun, subject and objects in the arrays so I was thinking that sentence=(subject+verb+object) is saying the input should consist of a subject, verb and an object

Comment: @DaphumlestNthabieMoloi wrong! I'd suggest that you do some more research and testing as your code has many issues. Then you'll be able to come back with more specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

this code is working ..

```
 <script language="javascript">
var noun=["cat","mat","rat"];
var verb=["like","is","see","sees"];
var object=["me","a+noun","the+noun"];
var subject=["I","a+noun","the+noun"];
var sentence=(subject+verb+object);

function checkCorrectness(){
    var input=document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    if(input==sentence.length)
        {
        alert("congratulations your sentence is correct");
        }
    else if(input==null || input =="")
        {
        alert("your entered a blank text, please enter sentence");
        }
    else{
        alert("Sorry, Your sentence is incorrect, your sentence should be in the form of a subject, verb and object. please try again");
        }
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1><font size="3" color="black" face="comic sans ms">Welcome to Micro English</font></h1>
<h2><font size="2" color="blue" face="comic sans ms">Please Enter a sentence in micro English in the box below</font></h2>

<form onsubmit="checkCorrectness();">
<input type="text" name="input" id="userInput"/>
<input type="submit"value`enter code here`="go"/>
</form>
```

Comment: this code is working but i am not satisfied with the line
   var sentence=(subject+verb+object);// what you want to do here

Answer (score 0):

`getElementbyId` is missing the capital `B` - should be `getElementById`

Also the things that I mentioned in the comments need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
var input=document.getElementbyId("userInput");
 var inputtext=input.value;
```

Now use inputtext instead of input for comparison.

Or just:

```
var input=document.getElementbyId("userInput").value;
```